BrokenProcessPool Error processing large data set
I am trying to process a large data set that has 167373 exercise logs. For context I am combining all coordinate data in each exercise log to create vectors and then calculating cosine similarity to find the most similar ones - which these may indicate common routes for running or biking. I need to write my code in dask/parallel and so far I think my code is breaking when I try to calculate the pairs of ID'd and their similarity scores.
For reference, the data passed into this looks tuples with sport type, ID, and array of coordinates: ( ('bike', 12, [1.234, 1.268, 40.69, 41.8, -1.2, -1.3]), ('bike', 12, [6.23, 6.268, 9.69, 9.8, -1.2, -1.3] )
def calculate_pairwise_cosine_similarities(group, threshold=0.95):                 # defining the function to calculate pairwise cosine similarities and filter those with score that is >= 0.95
    sport, records = group
    vectors = [record[2] for record in records]
    log_ids = [record[1] for record in records]

    
    pairs = [(i, j) for i in range(len(vectors)) for j in range(i + 1, len(vectors))]  # creating pairs of indices


    similarities = list(filter(lambda x: x[2] > threshold,                              
                               map(lambda pair: (log_ids[pair[0]], log_ids[pair[1]], cosine_similarity(vectors[pair[0]], vectors[pair[1]])), pairs)))

    return sport, similarities

When I run my code I get this error:
"BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process poo; was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending."
Does someone know how I could rewrite my function to be in parallel using 'Dask' operations or what this issue means?

Hi, do you have a complete reproducible example with example data? Where is Dask used in your code?

As @GuillaumeEB said you should have a look at [mcve] and [ask].
